# Compile to Intermediate type

Tags: c#

This is a learning for me.

**Compile to What Output type** or **How to Compile**  a `C# Class Library` to an `Intermediate File`, but `Not DLL`; which can be used in other project without having source code and not passing it to End User.

This is achievable in Delphi/C/C++ as per my knowledge.

Comment: so how do you achieve that in Delhpi or C++ ?

Comment: Yes, in Delphi it is and I worked on it.

Comment: @Tigran the OP is talking about object files and libraries - although these require header/link files even in Delphi in order to compile as they contain no metadata at all. But why do that? You don't need any source code to use a .NET assembly as it already contains all required metadata. Besides, the users no longer mind if an installation program adds 2 or 12 files - they never see this

Comment: @RJ1990 That's not how ILMerge works. It merges dlls/executables. It's not designed to handle other type of files (such as setting files)

Comment: Re your edit: that makes no sense - ILMerge processes *assemblies* - it has nothing whatsoever to do with ini / config files. I don't think you're using the tool correctly here...

Comment: @zespri : U were correct, meanwhile I created a sample to check and it is working.

Comment: @MarcGravell : U also correct, so I Re-edited my Post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> which can be used in other project without having source code and not passing it to End User.

It sounds to me like you should compile it to a dll, but perhaps consider [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=17630) as part of your build/deploy strategy. And frankly there is rarely any *good* reason not to simply ship the dll *without* merging.

Note that `csc` *does* allow you to output raw modules, via `/target:module` (presumably then re-combining with `/addmodule`) - but frankly that will be a real pain to work with.

Comment: ILMerge is good Tool, I tried, But can't use that.See Post again, I have modified it.

Comment: @RJ1990 I don't think you're using the tool correctly; it doesn't care about config files - that is not its job.