# Compile to Library other than DLL

Tags: c#

Here is one Question which I asked was
[Compile to Intermediate type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445551/c-sharp-compile-to-intermediate-type)

The problem was solved of Adding DLL into my Exe.

**Problem:**
My next problem to this is, these Libraries are big in size so I don't think it is feasible to do so. But In my project very few methods of those DLLs are being used.

**Question:**
Is there any alternative present for not Passing DLL to End user and also not merging DLL to Exe, like Compile to some intermediate file type which can be used in other project and only those parts(functions) are compiled with exe which are needed(used).

Comment: There's no facility like C/C++s static linking, if that's what you're trying to emulate.

Comment: (And in an environment where Reflection is available, analysis may not be possible to determine which parts of a DLL are actually used)

Comment: I don't think compilers have become that intelligent. You may have to code yourself, the only needed functions to another dll or to the exe itself.

Comment: It's quite unclear exactly what you are trying to do. As far as I understood question your problem is that you have compiled library that is _huge_ and your project has reference to this dll. When you want to deploy your application you have to deploy that big dll as well. But your project only uses little part of your library. So would not it be simpler to split your large dll into small libraries?

Comment: just out of curiosity, how big are the dll's?

Comment: Just a thought if the functions were organized into different namespaces and you only included some of those namespaces would the rest of them get compiled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in mechanism in .NET.

You could do one of the following:

- If these are your own dlls, split them.
- If not, ask the producer of the dlls to compile smaller files with certain functionality.
- If the license permits, you could decompile them and split it yourself.
- Rewrite the part you need.